# Azure Storage Explorer: How to query Table Storage Rowkey with "Contains"?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We are sending our logs to Azure Table Storage. I am trying to query those logs but finding it hard to do via Azure Storage Explorer.  I can't imagine why there is not a "contains" option to filter the RowKey column (where our actual log data is contained.)

[image]

Am I missing something obvious? Or is there a better tool for this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` unfortunately is not a supported query operator in Azure Table Storage.

For a list of supported/unsupported query operators, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service.

Comment: Ok. So.... what is your suggestion on how I find log entries that contain a certain value?

Comment: You will need to download the data on your local machine and then do a search. Is the information you're searching for appears at the beginning or it can be anywhere? For example, in the screenshot you shared above, would you be searching for `Information|` or `412600`?

Comment: A better column to look at is "RenderedMessage" In that one, the only data is exactly what we wrote. In this particular case, the data I want would come at the end of the string. But that might not always be the case. As for.... "You will need to download the data on your local machine and then do a search"... that's really unfortunate.  I hope MS improves this soon.  So much of working with Azure still requires these kinds of clunky workarounds.

Comment: `that's really unfortunate` - I completely agree. `I hope MS improves this soon` - I don't see it happening. It has been like this since 2008/2009 when this service was launched.

Comment: You may be better off writing these logs to App Insights/Log Analytics Workspace where you get much better query support (KQL).